# Windows 10 native bash does respond to tasks.json in VSCode

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-10, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using the new native bash on Windows 10.  I am trying to see any output in the VSCode console when I run a task that invokes the new bash.  For example, this works because its using cmd:

`tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "WHERE",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [ "bash" ],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Which gives me the result I would expect, and it prints it to the VSCode console: `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`.  This also shows me that cmd can see `bash.exe`.

Now, if I try to actually run bash from VSCode, I get nothing.  No output whatsoever. If I were to start up `cmd` as standalone, the following command would work: `bash -help`.  It would display the full bash help options inside the cmd window. But this `tasks.json` does not work:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "bash",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [ "-help" ],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

I initially thought that maybe the `cmd` that VSCode uses to call `bash` just wasn't displaying the output from bash. So I tried this task config to see if bash was even being executed, and it was not.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "bash",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [ "-c", "touch \"someFile.txt\"" ],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

If I run `bash -c "touch someFile.txt"` straight from `cmd`, it works as intended.  If I try it using the above `tasks.json`, it produces nothing.  It does not create the file, and it does not produce any output.

Do you guys have any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: I think I saw a similar post in here a few weeks back, but can't seem to find it :-) Have you tried with the full path to `/path/to/bash ` and a full path to `/c/Users/.../someFile.txt`?

Comment: That was the intent of the where command I used with `cmd.exe`.  I know VSCode can see the bash executable.  I also tired using the full path and relative path =/

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace "bash" with "c:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe"